# Using simple markup language - applying it

Tags: php, formatting, markup

I want to allow my users to add content. For making it easy i am going to use Textile or PHP Markdown.

I want to allow only the following formatting:

- bold or strong
- underline
- bullet list
- color of text

Nothing else. I can create a simple editor using jquery to surround with formatting tags.

So my questions:

- how to make Textile or Markdown allow only certain formatting(above listed formatting only i need) ?
- is it good to use textile or markdown? Or i should use free editors like tinyMCE? Which is best free editor(to use in my page) and also allows only formatting that i set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as markdown or an editor, I would say it depends on your visitors.  If they are not too tech-savvy then go with TinyMCE.  From the documentation, I cannot see anything about white listing or black listing.

#### Sanitize PHP:

Use:

[htmLawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/)

or

[Html Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: thanku. i liked ckeditor suggested by Abid Husaain. And it has `basic` toolbar which is exactly i want. But i have a doubt in license. Also if i use a editor the content submitted is html. So how to validate this content so to prevent javascript/malicious code injection?

Comment: @VppMan TinyMCE also has a basic toolbar you can set from JavaScript.  It is also free under the GPL license.  As far as sanitation.  Wait for an update to my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use ckeditor its free editor and his look and fill is very good and easy to setup.

Demo url :-

http://ckeditor.com/demo/ou

and you want to minimal editor tool you can see custom toolbar in demo

Download:-

http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: thanku. It is good editor. Two more questions: --If i want to store this html source in mysql database, what size should be given for field of type `TEXT` ?
--If i want to show text only(without formatting) from html source saved in database, what should i use? `strip_tags()` ?

Comment: yes your textfield should be textarea and data type would be "Text" and you can use strip_tags() for remove html tag

Comment: you can specify text type size then it is a fix. if you can fix size 255 char then you can store 255 char or you cant specify any size then you can store unlimited char store

Comment: If i omit size, no problem with performance of database or storage?

Comment: For commercial site, i have to buy commercial license? Is it ok if i do not make changes to anything(copyrights or creators name of CKeditor) ?

Comment: It is open source editor. Fully functional, open source editor, with source code included

Comment: Generated content from CKEditor is HTML. Correct? So, how to validate this content at my server(using PHP), to prevent HTML/javascript injection?